# Celery beat using supervisor in production

Tags: python, celery, supervisord, celerybeat

I am trying to run celery beat from my virtual env using supervisor. The script doesn't seem to work

All my supervisor scripts are in the directory `/etc/supervisord`
It has a `supervisord.conf` file and directory `conf.d` which contains the file `Gorgon-celery.conf`

My `supervisord.conf` file looks like this:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/tmp/supervisor.sock   ; (the path to the socket file)

[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisord/main.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
logfile_maxbytes=50MB        ; (max main logfile bytes b4 rotation;default 50MB)
logfile_backups=10           ; (num of main logfile rotation backups;default 10)
loglevel=info                ; (log level;default info; others: debug,warn,trace)
pidfile=/tmp/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
nodaemon=false               ; (start in foreground if true;default false)
minfds=1024                  ; (min. avail startup file descriptors;default 1024)
minprocs=200                 ; (min. avail process descriptors;default 200)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisord            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///tmp/supervisor.sock ; use a unix:// URL  for a unix socket

[include]
files = /etc/supervisord/conf.d/*.conf
```

My `Gorgon-celery.conf` file looks like this:

```
[program:Gorgon-celery]
command=cd /home/ubuntu/sites/source && source ../virtualenv/bin/activate && celery -A Gorgon worker
environment=PYTHONPATH=/home/ubuntu/sites/virtualenv/bin
directory=/home/ubuntu/sites/source
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celeryd/Gorgon.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celeryd/Gorgon.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600

[program:Gorgon-celerybeat]
command=cd /home/ubuntu/sites/source && source ../virtualenv/bin/activate && celery -A Gorgon beat --max-interval=10
environment=PYTHONPATH=/home/ubuntu/sites/virtualenv/bin
directory=/home/ubuntu/sites/source
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/var/log/celeryd/Gorgon-beat.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/celeryd/Gorgon-beat.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs = 600
```

Finally to the supervisor, I am using the command: `sudo supervisord -c /etc/supervisord/supervisord.conf`

Comment: When I use the command `ps aux | grep celery`, I get the output:  1001     23882  0.0  0.3  10468  2184 pts/2    S+   14:37   0:00 grep --color=auto celery

Comment: Does it work outside of supervisor? For example if you paste `command=cd /home/sourabh_workaholic_gmail_com/sites/source && source ../virtualenv/bin/activate && celery -A Gorgon beat --max-interval=10` into the shell.

Comment: Yes, it does work flawlessly.

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing

```
command=cd /home/sourabh_workaholic_gmail_com/sites/source && source ../virtualenv/bin/activate && celery -A Gorgon beat --max-interval=10
```

with

```
command=bash /home/sourabh_workaholic_gmail_com/script.sh
```

and now in `script.sh` and put the following:

```
#!/bin/bash    
cd /home/sourabh_workaholic_gmail_com/sites/source 
source ../virtualenv/bin/activate 
celery -A Gorgon beat --max-interval=10
```

I suspect you cannot use the `source` command with supervisorctl since it does not execute your command string in a shell. `source` is a command provided by the bash shell, so instead we put the commands in a `bash` script where they will work.

Comment: It seems to have worked, buy I just found a new flaw. The second scripts only seems to run celerybeat and skips celery.

Comment: You will need to create two separate bash scripts. One for celery, and one for celery beat.

Comment: I did do that. By the way this the output I get for: `ps aux|grep celery`
`root     24523  0.0  0.6  67904  4188 pts/2    T    14:50   0:00 sudo nano Gorgon-celery.conf`
`root     24524  0.0  0.7  14604  4704 pts/2    T    14:50   0:00 nano Gorgon-celery.conf`
`root     24620  0.1  7.6 174784 45968 ?        S    14:52   0:00 /home/sourabh_workaholic_gmail_com/sites/virtualenv/bin/python /home/sourabh_workaholic_gmail_com/sites/virtualenv/bin/celery -A Gorgon beat --max-interval=10`
`1001     25246  0.0  0.3  10468  2136 pts/2    S+   15:01   0:00 grep --color=auto celery`

Comment: What happens when you run the bash script for celery

Comment: Nothing, it just skips and runs celerybeat. I am using, "nohup celery -A Gorgon worker &" command to get it running.

Comment: i mean what happens when you run it manually from the shell. if you do that it shouldnt be running celerybeat.

Comment: If I manually run the bash script, celery runs without a hitch, with celerybeat already running under supervisor. But, it always skips the celery program and runs celerybeat program, I don't understand why.